# How to detect fill color option with pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have the following code section:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /tikz/.cd,
  color izquierda/.initial=\tikz@fillcolor,
  color derecha/.initial=\tikz@fillcolor,
}
```

It works, but if I don't have activated both options, I get an error if option 'fill=any color' is not selected. Please, can someone help me?. I also need to detect if fill option is selected. Thanks in advance!

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,makeshape}

\def\gap{0mm}

\makeatletter

% Dimensiones medidas en Autocad para las válvulas con anchura = 3mm en un
% círculo de 2mm de radio.

\def\radio@llave{2mm}
\def\x@llave{1.5mm}
\def\y@llave{1.32mm}

\pgfkeys{
    % Requiere que fill=color esté activado en caso de no estar izq. y dcha.
    /tikz/.cd,
    color izquierda/.initial=\tikz@fillcolor,
    color derecha/.initial=\tikz@fillcolor
}

%% Anchor path:

\def\llaveanchor{ % Obtiene la caja de texto correcta:

    \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
    \pgf@ya=\ctbney

    % Crea el margen para la forma:
    \advance\pgf@xa by \gap
    \advance\pgf@ya by \gap
    % Corrige minheight y minwidth, y outerxsep o outerysep:
    \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \advance\pgf@xa\pgfshapeouterxsep
    \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \advance\pgf@ya\pgfshapeouterysep
    % Dibuja el anchor con \pgfusepath{stroke}:
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose 
    % lo siguiente solo para comprobar
    %\pgfusepath{stroke}

}

%% Background path:

\def\llaveborder{ % Obtiene la caja de texto correcta:

    \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
    \pgf@ya=\ctbney

    % Crea el margen para la forma:
    \advance\pgf@xa by \gap
    \advance\pgf@ya by \gap
    % Corrige minheight y minwidth, y outerxsep o outerysep:
    \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \advance\pgf@xa\pgfshapeouterxsep
    \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \advance\pgf@ya\pgfshapeouterysep
    %
    % Dibuja el círculo:
    %
    \pgfcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\radio@llave}
    % con la opción clip evito los picos de la válvula saliendo el círculo
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke,clip}
    %
    % Triángulo izquierdo:
    %
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color izquierda}}
    %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\x@llave}{ \y@llave}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\x@llave}{-\y@llave}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
    %
    % Triángulo derecho:
    %
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color derecha}}
    %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ \x@llave}{ \y@llave}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ \x@llave}{-\y@llave}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
    %
    % Línea vertical:
    %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{ \radio@llave}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{-\radio@llave}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}

}

%% Declaración de la forma:

\pgfdeclareshape{llave toma en carga}{

    \setpaths{\llaveanchor}{\llaveborder}

    \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{
        \pgf@x = \ctbnex
        \pgf@y = \ctbney
        \advance\pgf@x by \gap
        \advance\pgf@y by \gap
        \mincorrect{\pgf@x}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
        \mincorrect{\pgf@y}{\pgfshapeminheight}
        \advance\pgf@x\pgfshapeouterxsep
        \advance\pgf@y\pgfshapeouterysep
    }

    % Anchors:
    \anchor{c}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=0pt}
    %
    \anchor{u}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y= \radio@llave}
    \anchor{d}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=-\radio@llave}
    \anchor{r}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \radio@llave \pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{l}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\radio@llave \pgf@y=0pt}
    %
    \anchor{ur}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \x@llave \pgf@y= \y@llave}
    \anchor{dr}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \x@llave \pgf@y=-\y@llave}
    \anchor{ul}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\x@llave \pgf@y= \y@llave}
    \anchor{dl}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\x@llave \pgf@y=-\y@llave}

}

\makeatother

\tikzset{
  st valvula/.style={
    draw,minimum width=3mm,minimum height=2.85mm,line width=0.1mm,inner sep=0em,scale=2
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

When 'fill' and 'color izquierda'/'color derecha' are commented, an error is obtained. A way to detect if 'fill' is uncommented is necesary.
Moreover, there would be feasible not to fill anything.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \node[%
    llave toma en carga,st valvula,scale=2,
    fill=gray!15,
    color izquierda=cyan,
    color derecha=red!50
  ] (v2) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

That yield:

[image]

Comment: There is the `.is if` key which you could use. Or am I misinterpreting the question? Do you want something like `.try`?

Comment: My main problem is that undertanding pgf manual cost me a big effort due to the English language. Then, could you post me an example of .is if. What I need is to have three different options in a new shape: fill, color izquierda (left color) y color derecha (right color), but in some cases I would need that fill is not activated.

Comment: Could you perhaps check if the `.is if` as used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468144/121799 is what you want? I have a feeling that you may be looking for `/.try` or `/.search also`.

Comment: I think this is not the solution because I need that \pgfsets detect if 'fill=COLOR' is done or not (no filling path). If yes, 'color izquierda' and 'color derecha' would take 'COLOR' as a default, and this works, but when neither 'color derecha' or 'color izquierda' and "fill' are not done I get an error 'Undefined color'. What I want is to have the posibility of not filling anything of the shape. I'm afraid I'm being a bit hopeless, and I'm grateful for your patience.

Comment: Could you please try to add a very minimal compilable example? I just do not fully understand your question.

Comment: I've just post a MWE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the silence but I am very busy. This seems to work and I left commented out `\typeout`s in to indicate how one can debug this.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,makeshape}

\def\gap{0mm}

\makeatletter

% Dimensiones medidas en Autocad para las válvulas con anchura = 3mm en un
% círculo de 2mm de radio.

\def\radio@llave{2mm}
\def\x@llave{1.5mm}
\def\y@llave{1.32mm}

\pgfkeys{
    % Requiere que fill=color esté activado en caso de no estar izq. y dcha.
    /tikz/.cd,
    color izquierda/.initial=\pgfutil@empty,
    %color izquierda/.default=\pgfutil@empty,
    color derecha/.initial=\pgfutil@empty%
}

%% Anchor path:

\def\llaveanchor{ % Obtiene la caja de texto correcta:

    \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
    \pgf@ya=\ctbney

    % Crea el margen para la forma:
    \advance\pgf@xa by \gap
    \advance\pgf@ya by \gap
    % Corrige minheight y minwidth, y outerxsep o outerysep:
    \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \advance\pgf@xa\pgfshapeouterxsep
    \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \advance\pgf@ya\pgfshapeouterysep
    % Dibuja el anchor con \pgfusepath{stroke}:
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose 
    % lo siguiente solo para comprobar
    %\pgfusepath{stroke}

}

%% Background path:

\def\llaveborder{ % Obtiene la caja de texto correcta:

    \pgf@xa=\ctbnex
    \pgf@ya=\ctbney

    % Crea el margen para la forma:
    \advance\pgf@xa by \gap
    \advance\pgf@ya by \gap
    % Corrige minheight y minwidth, y outerxsep o outerysep:
    \mincorrect{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \advance\pgf@xa\pgfshapeouterxsep
    \mincorrect{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \advance\pgf@ya\pgfshapeouterysep
    %
    % Dibuja el círculo:
    %
    \pgfcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\radio@llave}
    % con la opción clip evito los picos de la válvula saliendo el círculo
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke,clip}
    %
    % Triángulo izquierdo:
    %
    %\typeout{izquierda\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color izquierda}}
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color izquierda}}
    \ifx\pgfutil@tmpa\pgfutil@empty
         %\typeout{izquierda\space empty}
    \else
        \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color izquierda}}
    \fi 
    %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\x@llave}{ \y@llave}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\x@llave}{-\y@llave}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
    %
    % Triángulo derecho:
    %
    %\typeout{derecha\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color derecha}}
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color derecha}}
    \ifx\pgfutil@tmpa\pgfutil@empty
        %\typeout{derecha\space empty}
    \else
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color derecha}}
    \fi
    %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ \x@llave}{ \y@llave}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ \x@llave}{-\y@llave}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
    %
    % Línea vertical:
    %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{ \radio@llave}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{-\radio@llave}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}

}

%% Declaración de la forma:

\pgfdeclareshape{llave toma en carga}{

    \setpaths{\llaveanchor}{\llaveborder}

    \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{
        \pgf@x = \ctbnex
        \pgf@y = \ctbney
        \advance\pgf@x by \gap
        \advance\pgf@y by \gap
        \mincorrect{\pgf@x}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
        \mincorrect{\pgf@y}{\pgfshapeminheight}
        \advance\pgf@x\pgfshapeouterxsep
        \advance\pgf@y\pgfshapeouterysep
    }

    % Anchors:
    \anchor{c}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=0pt}
    %
    \anchor{u}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y= \radio@llave}
    \anchor{d}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=-\radio@llave}
    \anchor{r}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \radio@llave \pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{l}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\radio@llave \pgf@y=0pt}
    %
    \anchor{ur}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \x@llave \pgf@y= \y@llave}
    \anchor{dr}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \x@llave \pgf@y=-\y@llave}
    \anchor{ul}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\x@llave \pgf@y= \y@llave}
    \anchor{dl}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\x@llave \pgf@y=-\y@llave}

}

\makeatother

\tikzset{
  st valvula/.style={
    draw,minimum width=3mm,minimum height=2.85mm,line width=0.1mm,inner sep=0em,scale=2
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

When 'fill' and 'color izquierda'/'color derecha' are commented, an error is obtained. A way to detect if 'fill' is uncommented is necesary.
Moreover, there would be feasible not to fill anything.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \node[%
    llave toma en carga,st valvula,scale=2,
    fill=gray!15,
    %color izquierda=cyan,
    color derecha=red!50
  ] (v2) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your time. Now it works. Pure tex and pfg commands are pretty tricky for me and your are being very kind.